# iOS: Maintain Interactivity in centerPanel with JASidePanels when Menu Is Open

Tags: ios, jasidepanels

I am using [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) in a universal iOS app. I make the sidebar menu visible whenever the user is in landscape mode on an iPad, but it seems that when the menu is open, the `centerPanel`'s UI components become disabled. Tapping anywhere simply closes the menu, and then `centerPanel` interactivity resumes. But I want to keep the menu open and retain interactivity everywhere (similar to how Wunderlist does it).

**Is this possible with JASidePanels?** I have reviewed the class methods and don't see a related option, but I want to confirm before I rip it out and try a different menu system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is the only place `userInteractionEnabled` is changed:

https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels/blob/master/JASidePanels/Source/JASidePanelController.m#L244

Use KVO to watch this property:

https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels/blob/master/JASidePanels/Source/JASidePanelController.h#L139

and whenever it changes, make sure all of these views have `userInteractionEnabled = YES`

https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels/blob/master/JASidePanels/Source/JASidePanelController.h#L139